# iOS : 3.4: App names in iTunes Connect and as displayed on a device should be similar, so as not to cause confusion

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7

Just recently my app gone rejected.

Here is the reason apple says.

3.4: App names in iTunes Connect and as displayed on a device should be similar, so as not to cause confusion

can any one say how to resolve this error.

My app name is 10 character in device, and in iTunes connect it's 70 character,

How to done this in iTunes name is different and device app name is different.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't really a coding error, it's just down to Apple's rules to avoid confusing people. All you have to do is make your "App name" and the marketing name in iTunes, more similar.

Eg I could call my app "StackExchange" on the device and "Stack Exchange Community for iOS" on iTunes

But I couldn't call it "SuperCommunity" on the device and "Stack Exchange Community for iOS" on iTunes... because people may find it confusing.

Answer (score 0):

I've had one of my apps rejected for the same reason a year ago.
The problem of the reviewer was that the name on the App Store was too long (i was using keywords in the app's name) and on the device I had only the name (so that the app's name to not get clipped).

The issue wasn't really the fact that the App's name on the store does not match the name on the device but the fact that the app's name was including keywords.

Until I didn't changed the name on the App Store to perfectly match the name on the device, I got rejected 3 times.

So, you're a bit unlucky with your reviewer and you must change the name on the App Store with only your app's name and without any keywords attached to its name in any manner (like a phrase).

P.S. your reviewer could be the same one who reviewed me - because I have other apps that use a long name on the app store and a short one on the device and were approved without any issues.